# Efficient way to partition graph maximum and minimum number of cycles

Tags: graphs

Is there an efficient way to find the minimum and maximum number of edge disjoint cycles an undirected graph can be partitioned into, given that every vertex has an even degree?

Comment: As a function of some measure, like #edges or #vertices? Planar graph or general? What did you try, how far did you get?

Comment: (What's the CS angle?)